# Can I access the Apache Tiles definition name inside a ViewPreparer?

Tags: java, tiles2, apache-tiles

Is it possible to access the Apache Tiles definition name inside a ViewPreparer?

Comment: that's a very good question, bro. I've been looking for the same thing. I've submitted an issue on the apache foundation jira system, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TILES-564, hopefully they'll develop the feature.

Answer (score 1):

just add the attribute into the xml, eg

```
<definition name="t.*" extends="t.container">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/{1}.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="title" expression="${song.title} - ${song.author} in ${jukebox.name}"/>
    <put-attribute name="view" value="t.{1}"/>
</definition>
```